# How do I insert HTML code that references directives?

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

Because of performance issues with IE8, I need to insert selects via html.  But I need the select statements inserted to have Angular directives such as ng-model and ng-change.  When I run my code that inserts the selects the selects show just as expected, but the directive attributes such as ng-change do not operate.  The code I insert by setting the innerHTML is of the form:

```
<select ng-model='currentAccounts' ng-change='selectedAccountChanged()' >
      <option value='1'>option 1</option>
      <option value='2'>option 2</option>
</select>
```

How can I get these directives operational?

Update: To be clear about what I am doing here is the code that generates the select above.

```
  webServices.getAccounts()
  .then(function (result) {
    var str = "<select ng-model='currentAccounts' ng-change='selectedAccountChanged()' id='" + CHARGE_NUM_CONTROL_ID + "' style='width: 100%;' size='17' >";
     for (var i = 0; i < numAvailAccounts; i++) {
         str += "<option value='" + i + "'";
         if (i == 0) {
            str += " selected";       // select the 1st item
         }
         str += ">" + $scope.availableAccounts[i].Name + "</option>";
     }
     str += "</select>";
     ChargeNumPH.innerHTML = str;  // load all the options at once
  })
```

This code updates the contents of the following Div.

```
<div id="ChargeNumPH"></div>
```

(FWIW, I need the ng-change because when an item is selected it needs to appear in a string that displays the items selected.)

Ps. Inserting code this way is blazingly fast.  I was able to show a select with 1500 items 
in 50 msec. Using ng-option and IE8 took 9,000 msecs.

Comment: do you use a directive? can you show some more code?

Comment: Added the select generation code.

Answer (score 0):

ng-model and ng-change should still be hooked up just fine using that approach.  You can use ng-repeat to generate the option list but it may still lead to your performance issue.

```
<select ng-model='currentAccount' ng-change='selectedAccountChanged()'>
  <option ng-repeat="account in currentAccounts" value="{{account.value}}">{{account.text}}</option>
</select>
```

**I changed the ng-model to currentAccount and made currentAccounts the lookup array.

```
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.currentAccount = 1;

  $scope.currentAccounts = [
    { value: 1, text: 'option 1' },
    { value: 2, text: 'option 2' }
  ];

  $scope.selectedAccountChanged = function () {
    alert('currentAccount changed to ' + $scope.currentAccount);
  };
}
```

http://codepen.io/jessebibee/pen/bCvLG